# How can I get hotels and rooms Images (pictures) from Amadeus Self-Service API V3?

Tags: api, rest, amadeus

I'm trying to get hotels catalogue from Amadeus api v3, so far, I found all informations like name, rating, offers ... but still have to get pictures to display the returned data on a front-office.

I tried : `view=FULL` and `view=FULL_ALL_IMAGE` doesn't make any changes on the response.

Any help please ? :(

I tried also this request :

`'ghttps://api.amadeus.com/v3/hotels/images?hotelId={{Hotels_IDs}}&size=FULL&aspectRatio=16:9'`

I get this error message :

```
   `{
        "code": 38196,
        "title": "Resource not found",
        "detail": "The targeted resource doesn't exist",
        "status": 404
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hotel Search v3 doesn't return images. For workarounds check the [migration guide](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/migration-guides/hotel-search/#faq).